# How to add Unix timestamp to incoming Universal-Robots data in Python

Tags: python, xml, database, tcp, export-to-csv

I'm having problems while attempting to collect robot data using python over tcp socket.

Problems:
I can get robot tool position data from Universal Robots'(UR) Real Time Data Exchange (RTDE), using TCP/IP socket. But I can't get this data via Robot Operating System (ROS).

I can get 'Robotiq' force/torque data via ROS but not from RTDE.
Therefore I must collect data separately and join data together.

ROS uses Unix timestamp but the UR robot controller initiates its timestamp at zero on startup.

Therefore, how is one expected to merge these data?
Why would anyone initialise their timestamp at zero?

What I would like to know is; can I add my own system timestamp to this data by adding something like 'time.time()' somewhere in the provided python code?

www.universal-robots.com/how-tos-and-faqs/how-to/ur-how-tos/real-time-data-exchange-rtde-guide-22229/

At the bottom of the page on the above link, there is a package download for some example python code which demonstrates how RTDE parses and converts the incoming UR data into a .csv file.

The code uses dictionaries for the incoming data whose keys are in an xml file included in the package.

Everything I do it throws up an error because each piece of code seems to be expecting a certain number of args and I dont know enough about python to understant what's happening.
The script I was trying to alter in the package was 'record.py, see below. I imported time, then tried adding time.time() to various places to see what would happen. I got a lot of errors.

I've spent a whole day trying to work this out. Half of which was on trying to work out why UR had such a strange timestamp that didn't seem to match anything.

In case you don't want to open the package for yourself, below is the script 'record.py' that I think I should be able to add a timestamp to, but where???

```
#!/usr/bin/env/ python
import argparse
import logging
import sys
sys.path.append('..')
import rtde.rtde as rtde
import rtde.rtde_config as rtde_config
import rtde.csv_writer as csv_writer

#parameters
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('--host', default='localhost', help='name of host to connect to (localhost)')
parser.add_argument('--port', type=int, default=30004, help='port number (30004)')
parser.add_argument('--samples', type=int, default=0, help='number of samples to record')
parser.add_argument('--frequency', type=int, default=125, help='the sampling frequency in Herz')
parser.add_argument('--config', default='record_configuration.xml', help='data configuration file to use (record_configuration.xml)')
parser.add_argument('--output', default='robot_data.csv', help='data output file to write to (robot_data.csv)')
parser.add_argument("--verbose", help="increase output verbosity", action="store_true")
args = parser.parse_args()

if args.verbose:
    logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)

conf = rtde_config.ConfigFile(args.config)
output_names, output_types = conf.get_recipe('out')

con = rtde.RTDE(args.host, args.port)
con.connect()

# get controller version
con.get_controller_version()

# setup recipes
if not con.send_output_setup(output_names, output_types, frequency = args.frequency):
    logging.error('Unable to configure output')
    sys.exit()

#start data synchronization
if not con.send_start():
    logging.error('Unable to start synchronization')
    sys.exit()

with open(args.output, 'w') as csvfile:
    writer = csv_writer.CSVWriter(csvfile, output_names, output_types)
    writer.writeheader()

    i = 1
    keep_running = True
    while keep_running:

        if i%args.frequency == 0:
            if args.samples > 0:
                sys.stdout.write("\r")
                sys.stdout.write("{:.2%} done.".format(float(i)/float(args.samples))) 
                sys.stdout.flush()
            else:
                sys.stdout.write("\r")
                sys.stdout.write("{:3d} samples.".format(i)) 
                sys.stdout.flush()
        if args.samples > 0 and i >= args.samples:
            keep_running = False
        try:
            state = con.receive()
            if state is not None:
                writer.writerow(state)
            else:
                sys.exit()
        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            keep_running = False
        i += 1

sys.stdout.write("\rComplete!            \n")

con.send_pause()
con.disconnect()
```

After altering the code I was expecting to get a .csv file with a new first column called Timestamp populated with Unix timestamps per data entry.

What I got was garbage, no matter what I did.

Many thanks for your help.

Comment: There is an existing field in the xml file called timestamp, but that is the one that starts from zero each time. Would it be possible to overwrite this field with the new timestamp thus avoiding the need to add a new key to the dictionary?

Comment: I think I may be able to interrogate the robot controller to return only the system timestamp. In the same script, I could get the Unix timestamp from the pc. Now I will have three csv files. One with system timestamp, one with Unix timestamp and one with both system and Unix only. I should then be able to combine my csv files using this third file as a synchronisation key. Watch this space!